# Como actualizar valores contenidos en Radiobutton para utilizarlos en una funcion en Tkinter de Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, radiobutton

Estoy tratando de colocar tres opciones utilizando el widget Radiobutton para posteriormente utilizar el valor de la opcion seleccionada en una funcion cuando se oprima un boton.

He encontrado scripts donde se define una variable de tipo `IntVar` y luego se invoca el metodo `.get()` para obtener el valor de estos `Radiobuttons`, sin embargo no se resuelve mi problema.

La función que se llama al presionar el botón es:

```
def presiona_consultar(_mes,_year,_tr):
    print _mes
    print _year
    print _tr
```

La parte que define el radiobutton es:

```
tr = IntVar()
Radiobutton(lffecha, text="Anual", variable=tr , value= 1).place(x=10 , y=5)
Radiobutton(lffecha, text="Mensual", variable=tr , value= 2).place(x=110 , y=5)
Radiobutton(lffecha, text="Actual", variable=tr , value= 3).place(x=230 , y=5)
```

y el Boton es:

```
consultar = Button(inicio,text='Reporte',command= lambda : presiona_consultar(_mes=mes.get(),_year=year.get(),_tr= tr.get() )
consultar.place(x=535,y=600)
```

Al presionar "reporte" imprime correctamente el mes y el año (_mes,_year) los cuales programé con un widget Spinbox, pero al imprimir el tipo (_tr) solo imprime el valor 0, es decir, el .get() no obtiene los valores de los radiobutton Anual = 1, Mensual = 2 o Actual = 3

Mi ventana padre es `inicio=Tk()` y tengo un LabelFrame la cual llame `lffecha` que agrupa las opciones de los 3 Radiobuttons y los Spinbox mencionados anteriormente . A continuación el código que representa un modulo de mi app

```
from Tkinter import *
from valida import *


def presiona_salir(inicio):
    "VALIDA LA OPCION Yes/No"
    valida_salida         #FUNCION CONTENIDA EN EL MODULO valida
    if valida_salida() == True:
        print 'Saliste'
        inicio.destroy()
    else:
        print "Te quedaste"
    return #Funcion Sin Problemas !!


def presiona_consultar(_mes,_year,_tr):
    print _mes
    print _year
    print _tr


def inicio(user):
    "CREA LA PANTALLA DE GENERADOR DE REPORTE"
    inicio = Tk()
    inicio.title("INICIO")
    inicio.config(bg="gray")
    inicio.geometry("1280x670+25+20")
    inicio.resizable(width=False, height=False)  
    _user=(str("Usuario: ") )+ str(user.upper()).replace("."," ")
    saluda = Label(inicio, text = _user, bg="gray", font = ("Century Gothic",20))
    saluda.place(x=5,y=5)

    lffecha=LabelFrame(inicio,text='Consulta',bg="gray",labelanchor='n', height=300,width=340, font = ("Century Gothic",15))
    lffecha.place(x=10,y=75)

    tr = IntVar(value = 2)
    Radiobutton(lffecha, text="Anual", variable=tr , value= 1 , font = ("Century Gothic",14), bg="gray").place(x=10 , y=5)
    Radiobutton(lffecha, text="Mensual", variable=tr , value= 2 , font = ("Century Gothic",14), bg="gray").place(x=110 , y=5)
    Radiobutton(lffecha, text="Actual", variable=tr , value= 3 , font = ("Century Gothic",14), bg="gray").place(x=230 , y=5)

    mes=Spinbox(lffecha, values=('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'),wrap=True,width=12,font = ("Century Gothic",20),justify=CENTER)
    mes.place(x=7 , y=50)

    year=Spinbox(lffecha,from_=2012,to=2017,incremen=1,wrap=True,font = ("Century Gothic",20),width=6,justify=CENTER)
    year.place(x=215,y=50)

    consultar = Button(inicio,text='GENERAR REPORTE',font = ("Century Gothic",20) ,command= lambda : presiona_consultar(_mes=mes.get(),_year=year.get(),_tr=tr.get() ))
    consultar.place(x=535,y=600)

    salir = Button(inicio,text='Salir',font = ("Clarendon Light",15), relief=FLAT, bg="gray", fg="RED" , command=lambda       inicio=inicio:presiona_salir(inicio))
    salir.place(x=1210,y=10)

    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Problema resuelto, solo faltaba colocar dentro de los contenedores de la variable tr el labelframe. El codigo se resuelve sustituyendo la expresion `tr = IntVar()` por `tr = IntVar(lffecha)`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No deberias tener ningún problema en apariencia, usando tu código como base podemos reconstruir un código reproducible y que funciona correctamente:

```
from Tkinter import *

def presiona_consultar(_mes,_year,_tr):
    print _mes
    print _year
    print _tr

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

mes = StringVar(value='Marzo')
year = StringVar(value='2017')
tr = IntVar(value = 2)

Radiobutton(root, text="Anual", variable=tr, value=1).place(x=10 , y=5)
Radiobutton(root, text="Mensual", variable=tr , value= 2).place(x=110 , y=5)
Radiobutton(root, text="Actual", variable=tr , value= 3).place(x=230 , y=5)

consultar = Button(root,text='Reporte',command= lambda : presiona_consultar(_mes=mes.get(),_year=year.get(),_tr= tr.get() ))
consultar.place(x=120,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Por defecto ningun radiobutton estará seleccionado y la variable tiene valor 0, si se selecciona alguno el valor cambia correctamente. En mi ejemplo se inicializa la variable con un valor (2) lo que hace que al iniciar la app el radiobutton correspondiente (`Mensual`) esté seleccionado por defecto.

Si el problema no está en esto debe haber alguna información que se nos escapa como que son `lffecha` e `inicio` (frames, ventanas secundarias, dialogos, etc), cual es el padre de las variables, etc. Vendría bien que editaras la pregunta añadiendo un ejemplo mínimo que muestre tu problema pero funcional para que podamos reproducir el error y ver si podemos así detectar el problema.

Comment: El código que aportaste funciona sin problemas siempre y cuando este contenido en un mismo script. Sin embargo al implementar el cambio sugerido en mi codigo persiste el problema. Editaré la pregunta

Comment: Preegunta Editada !

Comment: He solucionado el problema.
Faltaba colocar dentro de los parentesis de la variable tr el LabelFrame. El problema se solucionó cambiando esta expresion `tr = IntVar()`  por esta  `tr = IntVar(lffecha)`

Comment: Ok @Javier, por eso te preguntaba antes de editar la pregunta que era lfecha y cual era el root de las variables porque lo único que se me ocurria que podría estar pasando era algo así. Me alegro que lo hayas resuelto, si necesitas ayuda otra vez recuerda colocar un ejemplo mínimo pero funcional para que podamos reproducir el problema(si es podible). Saludos.